# Find My indicates that my Mac is still at the thief's residence, but no option to erase

Tags: mac, find-my-mac

The Find My tracker indicates that my Mac is still at the residence of the person who stole it. I no longer have the option to erase the device and the picture of it has changed, but it still says locked. The plug was not stolen.

Comment: How did the 'picture of it' change? Having never been in this situation, I don't know what it looks like. Here's rundown from [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210515) about the Find My network.

Comment: If you know where your Mac is and you can prove that it is your Mac (say, using its serial number and proof of purchase, or perhaps data from Apple), can't you ask law enforcement to retrieve it?

Comment: the picture changed to an Apple Logo so we think it is dead.

Comment: Police won't go in because they say since its an apartment, not a house, they can't just knock on doors and search. Even though we pin pointed which apartment is was, since its a 1/2 way house, seems they have more rights than we do!